# error: ‘split’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, split

I get this compiler error from c++.  error: ‘split’ was not declared in this scope. I need help as i am not able to figure out why.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

string input;
string line;
 cout<< "Enter the input line" << endl;
while (getline(cin, line))
{   
    if (line == "quit")
    break;
     input = input + split(line, '#')[0];
}

 cout<< "The input entered was: "<<endl;
 cout<< input<< endl;

}
```

Comment: `split` isn't a part of c++

Comment: also you can't compare strings like that.

Comment: @DanielA.White, You missed the declaration. They're fine to compare here.

Comment: is there an alternate way to split a line in c++ beginning with a '#' character

Comment: @BrownieTuffy, Look at the related links to the right. I don't think `std::split` made it into C++14, either.

Comment: or even discard a sentence after a '#' character is come across anywhere in the line.

Comment: @BrownieTuffy, That's even easier. Just take the substring from 0 to `find('#')` (check out the string documentation if you don't know how to do that).

Comment: @DanielA.White Uh, yeah you can.

Comment: @chris: Indeed, it did not.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel mentioned, split is not part of C++.

You can consider using `boost::split`